# Dynamically increase/decrease number of threads at runtime in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I need to increase/decrease number of threads at runtime based on the data provided in logs

eg: If the log has thousands of requests in 1sec, then numberOfThreads should be high and in the next sec if the number of requests per sec has reduced, then numberOfThreads should be reduced and so on

First approach I tried is with Schedule Feedback Function with Throughput shaping timer and Concurrent thread group
but the problem I faced is startRPS and endRPS are to be assigned before hand, which doesnt work for me because my log has millions of requests at different RPS rate and assigning thousands of RPS statically is not feasible. Also tried to assign startRPS and endRPS programatically at runtime by defining user_defined_variables and changing them from preprocessor based on log, but throughput shaping timer took only the first values for startRPS and endRPS and didnt iterate through others. So the whole test has run on single set of RPS values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE9IX.png)

```
if(props.get("index") == null)
    props.put("index", 0);

int[] lst =  {15,20,31,21,99,50};

var i = vars.get("index");

if(i < lst.length)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        props.put("startRPS", "1");
        props.put("endRPS", lst[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        props.put("startRPS", lst[i-1]);
        props.put("endRPS", lst[i]);
    }
}

log.info("**** START: " + props.get("startRPS"));
log.info("**** END: " + props.get("endRPS"));

i = i + 1;
props.put("index", i);
```

Second approach I had tried is by adding JSR223 sampler, and setting number of threads based calculated number of requests per sec at runtime. This didnt work as well, numberOfThreads was always defaulted to 1 even after changing its value programatically

```
int num_of_reqs = Integer.parseInt(parsedString[1]);
int threadCount = num_of_reqs / 5;

log.info( "Num of reqs" + num_of_reqs +  "Threads: " + threadCount);

ctx.getThreadGroup().setNumThreads(threadCount);
props.put("threads", threadCount);

log.info("&&&&" + ctx.getThreadGroup ().getNumberOfThreads());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput), despite the word "constant" in its name it doesn't have to be constant, you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) for specifying the desired throughput and amend it from [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server), another Thread Group, using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), etc.

If additionally you want to change the number of threads (virtual users) you can do something like:

1. To add a new thread:

   ```
   ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(1,ctx.getEngine())
   ```
2. To stop a thread:

   ```
   ctx.getThreadGroup().stopThread('the name of the thread',false)
   ```